# How go generate a valid and random MAC address?

Tags: networking, mac-address

You probably know that MAC address can be generated, for instance, in the following way:

```
macaddr=$(dd if=/dev/random bs=1024 count=1 2>/dev/null|md5sum|sed 's/^\(..\)\(..\)\(..\)\(..\)\(..\)\(..\).*$/\1:\2:\3:\4:\5:\6/')
echo $macaddr
```

But this method can result in MAC address that looks like this one: `07:d4:51:9f:50:6c` . [You simply can't use the address](https://superuser.com/a/725472/274760) . If you tried, you would get this error:

```
# ip link set dev wlan0 address $macaddr
RTNETLINK answers: Cannot assign requested address
```

So the line above should be rewritten. And the question is how it should look like so the MAC address always was valid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. extract the first byte (e.g. `07` from your example)
2. bitwise AND it with decimal 254 (11111110 - all bits except zeroth bit set)
3. bitwise OR it with decimal 2 (00000010 - only 1st bit set)
4. combine the first byte back with the last five bytes

e.g.

```sh
#! /bin/sh

mac='07:d4:51:9f:50:6c'

lastfive=$( echo "$mac" | cut -d: -f 2-6 )
firstbyte=$( echo "$mac" | cut -d: -f 1 )

# make sure bit 0 (broadcast) of $firstbyte is not set,
# and bit 1 (local) is set.
# i.e. via bitwise AND with 254 and bitwise OR with 2.

firstbyte=$( printf '%02x' $(( 0x$firstbyte & 254 | 2)) )

mac="$firstbyte:$lastfive"

echo "$mac"
```

Output:

```
06:d4:51:9f:50:6c
```

`07` hex is `00000111` binary.   bitwise AND-ing it with `254` (`11111110` binary) results in `00000110` binary (6 decimal).  bitwise OR-ing it with `2` (`00000010` binary) results in no change because bit 1 is already set.  Final result is `06` hex.

Comment: I just tested and it looks like that it works just fine.

Comment: thanks for the edit. i didn't even notice that i missed the last byte.